# What is the code in Symfony to show a favicon?

Tags: symfony, favicon

After two days of trying to put a favicon on symfony, and after several tries, I still can't do it.
I was missing the webpack.encore.js file that I have now, however, nothing wants to be displayed.
Is there another code line with {{...}} ? Do i need to add asset somewhere ?

In another symfony project, this code worked:

```
<link rel="icon"
href="{{ '/images/' ~ 'mackay.jpg' }}"
type="image/x-icon"
src="" />
```

My favicons are in the folder templates/images/...

Thank you for your help.

Comment: There is no `src=""` attribute on `<link />`. Use `href=""` instead.

Comment: @Dai Thank you. I have tried but still nothing is working. :'(

Comment: The images need to be publicly accessible, try placing them in `public/images/..` instead of `templates/images/..`.

Answer (score 1):

```
<link rel="icon" type="image/jpg" href="{{ asset('img/favicon.jpg') }}" />
```

This works for me.